# Error posting images due to incorrect low reputation

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation, images

I just got the below error, when my reputation is currently 288. Is this a bug?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It seems a page refresh cleared this up. Would be good to examine logs, but if not interested, feel free to close.

Comment: I've sometimes noticed that the character count also throws an error, and I just reclick the Answer button

Comment: Not enough freehand red circles.